# A handful of files are not checked out correctly by Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have encountered a strange behavior:

Checking out a repository in Linux with the command line tool works just as expected. Running `svn status` after checkout reveals that everything is up-to-date as expected.

In Windows, I use Tortoise svn. After I do a check-out to a new folder, I see a few files flagged as "missing" right after check-out.

Examining the files, I see that there is indeed a difference between the files checked out in Linux and Windows. The Linux one is identical to the one in the repository, but the windows file is missing many rows with no obvious pattern.

I am using svn version 1.6.17
and
Tortoise version 1.9.5

Could there be a version conflict?

Comment: check the filenames: are those filenames valid on Windows? If not sure, try to create the file manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that someone in Linux had created files that differed only in capitalization:

Both `File.cpp` and `file.cpp` were located in the same directory. This caused confusion in Windows.